# Adding Swift or Enable Modules = YES on an Objective C project causes build errors

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

In Xcode 7.1 after adding a single swift file to a large Objective-C project, build fails with many "No visible @interface for XYZ declares the selector ABC" and "method definition for ABC not found" errors.

All these errors appear in one file only.

Adding a swift file automatically changed the build setting "Enable Modules" to "YES".  Changing this back to "NO" results in an error free build, but prevents mixing with swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an errant #import "header.h" in the middle of the file.  This was probably left over from some copy and paste in the past.

Seems that when enabling modules the compiler sees this header and marks the objective c class' @end at this point, meaning all method implementations after this were not being seen.

Due to my compiler setting of all warnings being treated as errors, I never saw this issue as the compiler stopped outputting errors after the max number had been displayed.